# HTTP Headers difference - load page incrementally

Tags: php, zend-framework, http-headers

I have an HTML page that shows a progress bar as it steps through a process. It uses flush() to send the data to the browser. I'm trying to get this to work in a Zend process which I'm short circuiting by specifically sending a header, content, then ending the process with an exit command.

The HTML page displays correctly (progress bar steps through being done). The Zend/PHP page only shows the finished page (not the steps). I'm assuming this is a header problem since the method (flush()) is identical.

In Chrome, the header for the HTML page comes up as:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Fri, 27 Jul 2012 14:38:07 GMT
Server: Apache/2.2.16 (Unix) mod_ssl/2.2.16 OpenSSL/0.9.8r DAV/2 PHP/5.3.2
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.3.2
Keep-Alive: timeout=5, max=100
Connection: Keep-Alive
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Content-Type: text/html
```

And the header for the Zend/PHP page comes up as:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Fri, 27 Jul 2012 14:44:13 GMT
Server: Apache/2.2.16 (Unix) mod_ssl/2.2.16 OpenSSL/0.9.8r DAV/2 PHP/5.3.2
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.3.2
Expires: Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT
Cache-Control: no-cache
Pragma: no-cache
Keep-Alive: timeout=5, max=98
Connection: Keep-Alive
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
```

The only header information I'm specifying in the PHP is:

```
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
```

I'm using this code from this page: http://w3shaman.com/article/php-progress-bar-script

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried using `ob_flush()` along with `flush()`? Zend could have output buffering activated.

Comment: To refine @MathieuImbert's point - you need to call `ob_flush()` **before** calling `flush()`.

Comment: I tried it previously and it didn't work but now it is. I'm assuming the method in the w3shaman.com is the difference. Thanks for the fix.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Call `ob_flush()` before you call `flush()` as Zend could have output buffering activated.

Answer (score 0):

Mathieu had the fix. Adding ob_flush() before flush() in the Zend/PHP page fixed the problem. I'm not sure if Zend is activating output buffering as suggested or not.